# how do I limit zsh completion initial listing's length?

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

When I use completion in zsh with the `menu select` style, if my proposition is ambiguous it initially displays the list of all possible completions. When that list exceeds the screen's size it asks if I want to see all the results, and if so displays it with a pager. Only when I'm done with the pager can I start to select a completion. Instead of that initial paged listing, I would like it to show only a screenful of matches, and a message saying that the list is shortened.

The question is : how may I achieve that ?

I'm aware that `zsh-autocomplete` has that functionality (but in a complete-as-you-type package). I believe it uses pseudo terminals and starts a new completion there to achieve that, as well as [`zsh-capture`](https://github.com/Valodim/zsh-capture-completion/blob/master/capture.zsh). I think it's a bit of an overkill for such a small feature. An answer that would prove me wrong would be welcome !

I tried to override `_complete`'s pager with `head` :

```
zstyle ':completion:._list_choices:list:' pager head
```

but it didn't change the completion's behaviour.

Comment: “I believe it uses virtual ttys and starts a new completion there to achieve that, as well as zsh-capture.” Hi, author of Zsh Autocomplete here. It uses neither of those. It simply uses a subprocess to determine how many lines would be generated, then preemptively trims off the excess before the completions are actually added to the system.

Comment: @MarlonRichert Nice to meet you ! I'm a fan of zsh-autocomplete, it's very capable.  I tried reading your code, and apparently was mistaken by [the `async.start` function](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete/blob/main/scripts/.autocomplete.async#L201). Would you develop just a little on the solution you implemented ? I'm mostly interested in the entry point - the way this subprocess triggers completion and reads the results to count the lines.

Comment: [Open a discussion](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete/discussions) on my repo, then we can have a proper conversation over there. 

Comment: Right, [did that](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete/discussions/560#discussion-4977743). Didn't even know about github discussions, looks great ! Also corrected my question's _virtual ttys_ to _pseudo terminals_ after considering `zsh-autocomplete` code again.